# Does android.hardware.Camera work for newer versions of android?

Tags: android, camera, nativescript, android-camera2

I am trying to use android.hardware.Camera on a newer version of android with nativescript.

I am getting "Fail to connect to camera service".

I know that android.hardware.Camera is marked as deprecated. But is the Camera class still functioning and able to work on newer android devices? Or is the deprication the reason why it can't connect to the camera service?

Comment: `android.hardware.Camera` is deprecated since API Level 21 (5.x), `android.hardware.camera2` APIs should be used instead. For more information, refer [official Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

The official release notes of Android 10 https://source.android.com/setup/start/android-10-release don't explicitly say this, but if you look at the API differences https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/29/changes.html, you will find that the old Camera APIs are finally marked as deprecated.

‏Does this mean that Android Q device may be built without hardware.Camera? Well, some time this will happen anyway. Possibly, with Android S.

Regarding your specific device, the cause could be different. I would suggest to try to run on it some basic camera app that uses the old API. The official Google sample should be good enough.

The error you see may result from some other app having not closed the camera gracefully. Power off should resolve such situation.